# Creating an organization on Hyperledger Grid gives me this Error

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

As I mentioned on the title, I would like to create an organization on Hyperledger Grid, basically I'm running on Splinter not a sawtooth,
So after fllowing the commands on the tutorial I'm just wanna test, I faced this error:
"error: Found argument '123 main street' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context"
That takes the adress '123 main street' as an argument and it's wasn't expected.
I tried to follow the structure on the --help, But I got the same Error.

Error: https://j.top4top.io/p_2280sldhn1.png

Running docker on splinter: https://l.top4top.io/p_2280khj412.png

I just followed the guide of the tutorial here on this link: https://grid.hyperledger.org/docs/0.1/creating_organizations.html#display-organizations-and-agents

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things:
firstly, the link that you posted is for version 0.1, while there is 0.3 now out.
https://grid.hyperledger.org/docs/0.3/using_pike.html
if you scroll to about have that page that I have mentioned, there is the instruction for creating an organisation, and you will see that it is slightly different. I have hit that wall myself.
In short, first create your org without any details, and then you can update that org with anything you need, like address, etc...

```
grid organization create myorg MyOrganization
```

and then you can update it so:

```
 grid organization update myorg MyOrganization --locations 'somewhere street 123, NY'
```

I hope this helps